# Hibernate / JPA: QueryException when hibernate generates metamodel for @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I try to persist an `@ElementCollection` within an entity with hibernate 4.3.1.Final. The entity looks like this:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Map;
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<CompositeKey, CompositeValue> map;

    @Embeddable
    public static class CompositeKey {
        @Basic
        private Integer key1;
        @Basic
        private Integer key2;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class CompositeValue {
        @Basic
        private Integer val1;
        @Basic
        private Integer val2;
    }
}
```

Hibernate generates the schema correctly:

```sql
create table MyEntity (id integer not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create table MyEntity_map (MyEntity_id integer not null, val1 integer, val2 integer, key1 integer, key2 integer, primary key (MyEntity_id, key1, key2)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create table ReferencedEntity (id integer not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table MyEntity_map add constraint FK_mhu8q8dtieguddm0w4gxfwhnc foreign key (MyEntity_id) references MyEntity (id);
```

[image: Generated schema]

But when I change `CompositeKey` to reference another `Entity`, I get a `QueryException` when hibernate generates the metamodel on startup.

The changed code:

```java
@Embeddable
public static class CompositeKey {
    @ManyToOne
    private ReferencedEntity key1;
    @Basic
    private Integer key2;
}
```

The referenced `Entity`:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class ReferencedEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
}
```

The Exception:

```text
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: key1 of: component[val1,val2]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83) ~[AbstractPropertyMapping.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toColumns(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:98) ~[AbstractPropertyMapping.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.toColumns(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1625) ~[AbstractCollectionPersister.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CompositePropertyMapping.toColumns(CompositePropertyMapping.java:124) ~[CompositePropertyMapping.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CompositeQuerySpaceImpl.toAliasedColumns(CompositeQuerySpaceImpl.java:52) ~[CompositeQuerySpaceImpl.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.JoinImpl.resolveAliasedLeftHandSideJoinConditionColumns(JoinImpl.java:79) ~[JoinImpl.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.addJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:261) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.renderEntityJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:193) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.renderJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:158) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:137) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:132) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:138) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:132) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:113) ~[LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadQueryDetails.generate(AbstractLoadQueryDetails.java:171) ~[AbstractLoadQueryDetails.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.BasicCollectionLoadQueryDetails.<init>(BasicCollectionLoadQueryDetails.java:60) ~[BasicCollectionLoadQueryDetails.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.makeCollectionLoadQueryDetails(BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.java:101) ~[BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.<init>(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:77) ~[AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.CollectionLoader.<init>(CollectionLoader.java:112) ~[CollectionLoader.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.CollectionLoader$Builder.byKey(CollectionLoader.java:105) ~[CollectionLoader$Builder.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.buildNonBatchingLoader(AbstractBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:45) ~[AbstractBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.createBatchingCollectionInitializer(BatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:71) ~[BatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.createCollectionInitializer(BasicCollectionPersister.java:343) ~[BasicCollectionPersister.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:676) ~[AbstractCollectionPersister.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484) ~[SessionFactoryImpl.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) ~[Configuration.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) ~[EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) ~[ClassLoaderServiceImpl.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150) ~[HibernatePersistenceProvider.class:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ...
```

What is wrong with my mapping? How can I prevent this exception?

It is interesting, that the `BasicCollectionPersister` seems to get initialized correctly. Debugging shows, that e.g. the `sqlUpdateRowString` is `update MyEntity_map set val1=?, val2=? where MyEntity_id=? and key1_id=? and key2=?`.

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: I'm using hibernate 4.3.1.Final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the JPA 2.0 specification:

> Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported.

See also [JPA - EmbeddedId with @ManytoOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705130/jpa-embeddedid-with-manytoone).

**EDIT:**

Hibernate 4.3.1.Final implements JPA 2.1, so my first guess was wrong. Mea culpa.

The problem with the mapping is the use of `@ElementCollection` with an embeddable `CompositeKey` referencing to the entity `ReferencedEntity`. The exception in `AbstractPropertyMapping` is thrown when Hibernate looks for a reference from `CompositeValue` (sic!) to `ReferencedEntity`. However as no such relation exists, the exception is thrown. For me it is unclear if this is a Hibernate bug or according the JPA 2.1 specs.

I see following solutions.

**Solution 1**

Change `CompositeKey` to an `Entity` adding an `id` field. In this case the `@OneToMany` annotation could be used:

```
@Entity
public class CompositeKey {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ReferencedEntity.class)
    private ReferencedEntity key1;

    @Basic
    private Integer key2;

}
```

**Solution 2**

Add an additional entity `CompositeSampler` containing `CompositeKey` as the ID and `CompositeValue` as an additional attribute. `MyEntity` will contain a list of `CompositeSampler`.

**Solution 3**

Add a reference from `CompositeValue` to `ReferencedEntity`.

By the way, according the JPA 2.1 specs: "If an embeddable class is used as a map key, the embeddable class must implement the hashCode and equals methods consistently with the database columns to which the embeddable is mapped".

Comment: Is there a workaround except for declaring `CompositeKey` as `@Entity`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is really the problem, because hibernate maps `@EmbeddedId`s with `@ManyToOne` elements as expected and generates the foreign key correctly. And I'm not even using an `@EmbeddedId` in the code posted above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Solution 1 is what I meant by my first comment to your answer. I think that it is a bug in hibernate, because I was able to make hibernate generate the schema when I renamed the field `key1` to `val1`. It finds the properties name in `CompositeValue` and doesn't complain further. But I didn't test whether the entity _behaves_ as expected (CRUD). I think I'll file a bug report.